# Sqlite shows EXC_BAD_ACCESS in ios SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

This code is work perfectly in iphone,ipad simulator in both `xcode 4.5` and `xcode 4.6`.Also Debug perfectly with device in `xcode 4.5`.
but when i am trying to debug device in xcode 4.6.2 then this error shows.

**This is the Query**

```
NSString *insertQuery=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Insert into %@ (ID,Question,Answer,Option1,Option2,Option3,Explanation,ImageName,Used) values(%d,'%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','%@')",table,[[d objectForKey:@"ID"]intValue],[d objectForKey:@"Question"],[d objectForKey:@"Answer"],[d objectForKey:@"Option1"],[d objectForKey:@"Option2"],[d objectForKey:@"Option3"],[d objectForKey:@"Explanation"],[d objectForKey:@"ImageName"],@"N"];
                        NSLog(@"insert query-%@",insertQuery);
                        [database executeNonQuery:insertQuery];
```

**here is the code which shows the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error**

```
- (BOOL)executeNonQuery:(NSString *)sql, ... 
    {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, sql);

    NSMutableArray *argsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSUInteger i;
    for (i = 0; i < [sql length]; ++i)
         {
        if ([sql characterAtIndex:i] == '?')

                   [argsArray addObject:va_arg(args, id)]; //This line shows error.
    }

    va_end(args);

    BOOL success = [self executeNonQuery:sql arguments:argsArray];

    [argsArray release];
    return success;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Boy howdy that is some dangerous code; unprotected query composition + parsing!  SQL Injection Attack potential is high!

The problem is that you are interpreting dynamically generated string contents with no consideration for what is in the strings.   The version of Xcode is irrelevant.

When you compose your `insertQuery` and then pass it to `executeNonQuery:`, if that string contains any `?` characters, then that will require another argument be passed to that method.

I.e. say `[[d objectForKey:@"ID"]intValue]` returns `@"fd?Edfds???sdfefsads?f?"`;  that'll be interpreted as needing six arguments in your `executeNonQuery:` method.

**BOOM**

If you are going to compose a complete query into your `insertQuery` string, then you would need to pass it to whatever can directly evaluate the SQL.   Looking at the call, I'd bet that `executeNonQuery:arguments:` will make yet another pass through the string and/or arguments to bind arguments to the `?`s.

Comment: thanks for reply..but i am still confuse please give me an example how can i pass query directly to [database executenonquery:...]

Comment: [database executeNonQuery: @"INSERT INTO ? VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);",table,[[d objectForKey:@"ID"]intValue],[d objectForKey:@"Question"],[d objectForKey:@"Answer"],[d objectForKey:@"Option1"],[d objectForKey:@"Option2"],[d objectForKey:@"Option3"],[d objectForKey:@"Explanation"],[d objectForKey:@"ImageName"],@"N"];     //i tried this am i right..?

Comment: That would seem to be how the API is designed, yes.